# Make an array of orders for each month with Laravel Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am not too familiar with Laravel Carbon and I would like to be able to group in a table the number of orders made for each month of the year. For example, if I have 4 orders in January, 8 orders in February, 16 orders in March the table would look like this:

```
[4,8,16,...]
```

My database look like this:

[image: db face]

I have searched a lot without finding too many solutions but I know that it is possible with Laravel Carbon... If you could give me a lead I wouldn't say no!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I got it right, it will work for you.

```
    $data = Table::select([
        DB::raw('count(id) as orders'),
        DB::raw('month(created_at) as month'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```